# Google GCP cloud run redis client loses connection to the instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, node-redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I am running my nodejs application on google cloudrun. My application connects to google memorystore redis. Every few mins am getting the following error

Error: read Connection Reset

Followed by

AbortError: Redis connection lost and command aborted. It might have been processed.

Please help what am I missing?

My nodejs code

```
const redis = require('redis')

const redisClient = redis.createClient({host:'xxx', port: 6379})
redisClient.on('error, function (err) {
console.log(err)
}

const data = await redisClient.getExAsync('key')
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be caused due a socket time out. This is expected to happen when there is no activity for a period of time.

This could be avoided by periodically executing any command on the connection, for example one command per minute, so it will keep the socket alive and will not abort the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Use "setInterval" function in order to invoke Redis operation every minute.

```
async function RedisKA() {
  client.get("key2", (err, reply) => {
    console.log(`${kaCount} redis keep `);
  });

}

let updateIntervalId = setInterval(RedisKA, 60000);
```

If you want to avoid the request timeout on the [Cloud Run side](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout), which is 5 minutes by default then set your value based on your requirement.

Comment: I am using the redis in restapi. So the above code cannot invoke every 1 seconds forever.  Is there any inbuilt retry mechanism in redis nodejs module I can use. Also I have used all the redis logic with await/async(with bluebird promisify)  model.